# drawing to canvas on android motion events

Tags: android, canvas, touch-event

I'm new to programming and have been mostly self teaching and using books with lots of help from questions other people have asked in this forum.
I am currently working through android game development for dummies and have run into several problems most of which I have been able to solve myself but this compiler error I can't make go away. it' doesn't recognise the canvas.drawCircle in the code. and I can't figure out why.
any help or thoughts very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Tom

```
public class CrazyEightsView extends View {

    private Paint redPaint;
    private int circleX;
    private int circleY;
    private float radius;

    public  CrazyEightsView(Context context) {
        super(context) ;
        redPaint = new Paint();
        redPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        redPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(99, 00, 00));
        circleX=100;
        circleY=100;
        radius=30;      
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {

    }


    public  boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();
        int X =(int)event.getX();
        int Y =(int)event.getY();

        switch (eventaction){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                circleX = X;
                circleY = Y;
                break;

                invalidate();
                return true;
        }

        canvas.drawCircle (circleX, circleY, radius, redPaint); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Move this inside the draw method

          canvas.drawCircle (circleX, circleY, radius, redPaint);

invalidate() will refresh the draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Raghunandan sais, do not try to draw in any method other than `onDraw()`. Set your `X` and `Y` values in `onTouch()` and then invalidate the view. This will call `onDraw()` again.

Comment: Thanks for anyone else with a similar issue this is what my code looks like now 
@Override
public void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {canvas.drawCircle (circleX, circleY, radius, redPaint);
invalidate();
}public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
   int eventaction = event.getAction();
   int X =(int)event.getX();
   int Y =(int)event.getY();
  switch (eventaction){
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    circleX = X;
    circleY = Y;
    break;
    default:
   }
    return true;

Answer (score 0):

Move this inside the draw method

```
      canvas.drawCircle (circleX, circleY, radius, redPaint);
```

To force a view to draw, call invalidate().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

invalidate() will refresh the draw (calls onDraw(canvas).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Modify the below according to your needs.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CrazyEightsView ev= new CrazyEightsView(this);

    setContentView(ev);
}

public class CrazyEightsView extends View {

    private Paint redPaint;
    private int circleX;
    private int circleY;
    private float radius;

    public  CrazyEightsView(Context context) {
        super(context) ;
        redPaint = new Paint();
        redPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        redPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(99, 00, 00));
        circleX=100;
        circleY=100;
        radius=30;

    }
    @Override

    public void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
                    // draw your circle on the canvas
        canvas.drawCircle (circleX, circleY, radius, redPaint);
    }

    public  boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
            int eventaction = event.getAction();
            int X =(int)event.getX();
            int Y =(int)event.getY();

            switch (eventaction){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                circleX = X;
                circleY = Y;
                invalidate();// call invalidate to refresh the draw
                break;

            }
            return true;
    }
    }

 }
```

[image]